# React Native Facebook User Parse Authentication via magus/react-native-facebook-login

Tags: facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login, react-native

Can't seem to figure the proper way to persist data into Parse via the magus/react-native-facebook-login module after getting the user token from facebook. The problem is, that when I attempt to persist the data with the following code:

```
onFbSignupPress: function() {

        var that=this;

        //sign up/login via facebook and store credentials into parse
        //need approval  "user_likes", "user_about_me", "user_actions.music", "user_actions.news", "user_actions.books"
        FBLoginManager.loginWithPermissions(["email","user_friends", "public_profile", "user_likes", "user_about_me", "user_actions.music", "user_actions.news", "user_actions.books"], function(error, data){
          if (!error) {

            var authData = {
                id: data.credentials.userId,
                access_token: data.credentials.token,
                expiration_date: data.credentials.tokenExpirationDate
             };
             //console indicating success
             console.log(authData.id);
             console.log(authData.access_token);
             console.log(authData.expiration_date);


             //sign up into parse db
             Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(authData, {
                  success: (user) => {
                    if (user.existed()) {
                      // login: nothing to do
                      console.log('User Already Logged In');
                      that.setState({loadingCurrentUser: false});
                      that.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{ name: 'home'}]);
                    } else {
                      // signup: update user data, e.g. email
                      console.log('getting user additional information');
                      var data = user.get('authData').facebook;
                      var api = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/'+data.id+'?fields=name,email&access_token='+data.access_token;

                      var fetchProfile = new FBSDKGraphRequest((error, result) => {
                        if (error) {
                          // TODO: error
                          this.setState({loadingCurrentUser: false});
                        } else {
                          console.log(result);
                          var name = responseData.name;
                          var email = responseData.email;

                          // FIXME: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact/issues/45
                          var userId = {
                            className: '_User',
                            objectId: user.id
                          };

                          ParseReact.Mutation.Set(userId, {
                            username: email,
                            email: email,
                            name: name
                          }).dispatch();

                          that.setState({loadingCurrentUser: false});
                          that.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{ name: 'onboarding'}]);
                        }
                      }, '/me?fields=name,email');
                      // FIXME https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/20
                      // fetchProfile.start();
                      FBSDKGraphRequestManager.batchRequests([fetchProfile], function() {}, 10)
                    }
                  },
                  error: (user, error) => {
                    console.log('Error', error.message);
                    switch (error.code) {
                      case Parse.Error.INVALID_SESSION_TOKEN:
                        Parse.User.logOut().then(() => {
                          this.onFacebookLogin(token);
                        });
                        break;
                      default:
                        // TODO: error
                    }
                    that.setState({loadingCurrentUser: false});
                    that.setState({errorMessage: error.message});
                  }
                });

          } else {
            console.log('User did not succesfully log in');
            console.log("Error: ", error);
            that.setState({errorMessage: error.message});
          }
        });
    },
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Which i don't quite understand after attempting to .bind(this) parts of the function that I thought were causing the error. I'm a novice so appreciate any help - here's my code so far:

```
//component that opens up app to signup screen
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    View, 
    Text, 
    StyleSheet,
    Image,  
    TextInput,
} = React;

//additional libraries (FBSDK, Facebook Login, Parse React)
var Parse = require('parse/react-native');
var ParseReact = require('parse-react/react-native');
var FBLoginManager = require('NativeModules').FBLoginManager;
var FBSDKCore = require('react-native-fbsdkcore');
var {
  FBSDKGraphRequest,
  FBSDKGraphRequestManager, 
} = FBSDKCore;


//dimensions
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var window = Dimensions.get('window');

//dynamic variable components
var ImageButton = require('../common/imageButton');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        style: View.propTypes.style,
        onFbSignupPress: React.PropTypes.func,
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
        FBLoginManager.getCredentials(function(error, data){
          if (!error) {
            console.log("Login data: ", data);
          }
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            username: '', 
            password: '', 
            errorMessage: '',
            passwordConfirmation: '',
            loadingCurrentUser: true, 
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container]}>
                <Image 
                    style={styles.bg} 
                    source={require('./img/login_bg1_3x.png')}>
                    <View style={[styles.header, this.border('red')]} >
                        <View style={styles.headerWrapper} >
                            <Image 
                                style={[styles.login_brand]}
                                resizeMode={"contain"}
                                source={require('./img/signup_brand.png')} />
                            <ImageButton
                                style={[styles.fb_btn]}
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                                onPress={this.onFbSignupPress}
                                source={require('./img/fb_signup_btn.png')} />
                            <Image 
                                style={[styles.loginBar]}
                                style={[styles.loginBar]} 
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                                source={require('./img/login_bar_3x.png')} />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View style={[styles.footer, this.border('blue')]} >
                        <View style={styles.footerWrapper} >
                            <Text style={styles.error}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
                            <TextInput 
                                placeholder={'Email'}
                                style={styles.input} 
                                value={this.state.username}
                                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})} />
                            <TextInput 
                                placeholder={'Password'}
                                secureTextEntry={true} 
                                style={styles.input} 
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})} />
                            <TextInput 
                                placeholder={'Confirm Password'}
                                secureTextEntry={true} 
                                style={styles.input} 
                                value={this.state.confirmPassword}
                                onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({passwordConfirmation: text})} />
                            <ImageButton
                                style={[styles.email_btn]}
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                                onPress={this.onCreateAcctPress}
                                source={require('./img/get_started_btn.png')} />
                            <ImageButton
                                style={[styles.email_btn]}
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                                onPress={this.onAlreadyAcctPress}
                                source={require('./img/already_acct_btn.png')} />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Image>
            </View>
        );
    }, 
    onFbSignupPress: function() {

        var that=this;

        //sign up/login via facebook and store credentials into parse
        //need approval  "user_likes", "user_about_me", "user_actions.music", "user_actions.news", "user_actions.books"
        FBLoginManager.loginWithPermissions(["email","user_friends", "public_profile", "user_likes", "user_about_me", "user_actions.music", "user_actions.news", "user_actions.books"], function(error, data){
          if (!error) {

            var authData = {
                id: data.credentials.userId,
                access_token: data.credentials.token,
                expiration_date: data.credentials.tokenExpirationDate
             };
             //console indicating success
             console.log(authData.id);
             console.log(authData.access_token);
             console.log(authData.expiration_date);


             //sign up into parse db
             Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(authData, {
                  success: (user) => {
                    if (user.existed()) {
                      // login: nothing to do
                      console.log('User Already Logged In');
                      that.setState({loadingCurrentUser: false});
                      that.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{ name: 'home'}]);
                    } else {
                      // signup: update user data, e.g. email
                      console.log('getting user additional information');
                      var data = user.get('authData').facebook;
                      var api = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/'+data.id+'?fields=name,email&access_token='+data.access_token;

                      var fetchProfile = new FBSDKGraphRequest((error, result) => {
                        if (error) {
                          // TODO: error
                          this.setState({loadingCurrentUser: false});
                        } else {
                          console.log(result);
                          var name = responseData.name;
                          var email = responseData.email;

                          // FIXME: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact/issues/45
                          var userId = {
                            className: '_User',
                            objectId: user.id
                          };

                          ParseReact.Mutation.Set(userId, {
                            username: email,
                            email: email,
                            name: name
                          }).dispatch();

                          that.setState({loadingCurrentUser: false});
                          that.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{ name: 'onboarding'}]);
                        }
                      }, '/me?fields=name,email');
                      // FIXME https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/20
                      // fetchProfile.start();
                      FBSDKGraphRequestManager.batchRequests([fetchProfile], function() {}, 10)
                    }
                  },
                  error: (user, error) => {
                    console.log('Error', error.message);
                    switch (error.code) {
                      case Parse.Error.INVALID_SESSION_TOKEN:
                        Parse.User.logOut().then(() => {
                          this.onFacebookLogin(token);
                        });
                        break;
                      default:
                        // TODO: error
                    }
                    that.setState({loadingCurrentUser: false});
                    that.setState({errorMessage: error.message});
                  }
                });

          } else {
            console.log('User did not succesfully log in');
            console.log("Error: ", error);
            that.setState({errorMessage: error.message});
          }
        });
    },
    onCreateAcctPress: function() {
        if (this.state.password === this.state.passwordConfirmation)
        {   
            var user = new Parse.User();
                user.set("username", this.state.username);
                user.set("password", this.state.password);
                user.set("email", this.state.username);

                user.signUp(null, {
                  //navigate to new component (.immediatelyResetRouteStack)
                  //when doing so and we pass new views of app (routes)
                  success: (user) => { this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([{ name: 'onboarding'}]); },
                  error: (user, error) => { this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }); }
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: "Your passwords are not the same!"});
        }
    },
    onAlreadyAcctPress: function() {
        this.props.navigator.pop();
    },
     //function that helps with laying out flexbox itmes 
     //takes a color argument to construct border, this is an additional 
     //style because we dont want to mess up our real styling 
     border: function(color) {
        return {
          //borderColor: color, 
          //borderWidth: 4,
        } 
     },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've missed some functions being set on your button components directly, e.g.:

```
onPress={this.onFbSignupPress}
...
onPress={this.onAlreadyAcctPress}
```

Change all of these remaining functions to arrow functions or bind:

```
onPress={() => this.onFbSignupPress()}

onPress={this.onFbSignupPress.bind(this)}
```

I prefer the former style.

Two side notes for you:

1. No need to use _this or .bind, just use arrow functions everywhere instead.
2. Instead of doing `onCreateAcctPress: function() {` for example (which creates an **anonymous** function and binds it to the property "onCreateAcctPress") you should instead create a **named** function which can be done easily in ES6: `onCreateAcctPress() { ... }`.  It's why your stack has an `<unknown>` in it.

Comment: @RobertTomasGIV Great!  If this answers your question, please be sure to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Well, unfortunately it doesn't quite attend to my question though it does help my formatting - react already binds the function for me so the buttons work properly when pressed - I just don't know how to store the auth object into parse once I have the necessary user information - do you know how to do this?

Comment: that's why i left the "//sign up into parse db" line for more code to actually sign in with that data afterwards.

Comment: onCreateAcctPress() works when users sign in via email but onFbSignupPress() only gets the data, it doesn't store it in parse

Comment: Are you still getting that same error?  Because that still looks like a context issue.  Also, if you're using latest React, it does not bind for you in any way, that's just native JavaScript binding.

Comment: @AdamTerlson5 yeah the problem has been fixed, now just need to find a way to get user email from Facebook into parse - seems not to be working  - i have update current code, would appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't completely understand the suggestion to "instead create a named function." You can't just replace the existing, anonymous function inline with `React.createClass` with a named function, since `createClass` expects an Object. You could create named functions which sit outside this call, but then your `this` binding gets more complex. Am I misunderstanding something?